# jQuery datetimepicker not fillup data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

my case was very simple **datetimepicker** but something went wrong

My Html code:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="endTime" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
    });
});
```

The popup show well but when I click to each day or time on it, nothing happen on textfield **(input)**, I'm using asp.

What's my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: why mix jQuery and angular?

Comment: Hi @gaetanoM, is angular can care everything? I'm newbie in angular and sometime i mix it to interact HTML DOM. Should I do it?

Comment: Isn't the id supposed to be on the input itself and not the div around it? You could use showOn in your datetimepicker config to add the click handler to a different element

Comment: It's not a good practice. But in any case you can do wather you want.

Comment: @gaetanoM, yes, any case, just sometime, i always lay angular in priority

Comment: I add         `$("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii' });`
and it works :(

Comment: just to clarify/correct myself. showOn sadly only is implemented in the jQuery UI datepicker, but not in the datetimepicker from xdan.